# Gather artifacts of different build plans for combined build

Tags: build, bamboo

The project I'm working on is composed out of three parts. All three have there own build plan in bamboo.

I know want to create a build plan where I gather the artifacts of those plans and do some combined tasks on them. The three parts are developed on there own speed so I need to be able to tell which build it needs to take from every component. I can't just take the last correctly build artifacts of every build plan because component A might already be further in development then component B and C.

How can I do this because I'm only able to download the latest artifacts of a certain build plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Bamboo can't handle your option. One of the way I see here is to use some artifact storage: Nexus, Artifactory whatever which will store your artifacts from different plans. And then in that gathering plan you can configure Bamboo to download these artifacts by some path defined for example by plan variable to point correct version of A, B and C plan